# Issue trying to install ElasticSearch plugins in Mac OS El Capitan

Tags: macos, plugins, elasticsearch, installation, elasticsearch-marvel

I've been trying to install marvel plugin in elastic search.

I've already installed ElasticSearch as following:

```
brew update
brew install elasticsearch
```

This installed the 2.3.1 version.

Accordingly to the instructions, to install a plugin I had to go to the ES folder/bin and use the plugin script.

But in that folder there was no plugin script that helped me install the plugins. All there was in the bin folder was the elasticsearch script.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS, the `plugin` executable should be available in `/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/bin/plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Follow next command and see where plugin system is installed `brew list elasticsearch|grep -m1 plugin`